# Isolating the line in /etc/passwd that contains "string" using grep

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a list of "tasks" which I go through to learn the shell-code, I need to use grep to isolate the line in `/etc/passwd` that contains “`ubu`”. 
I know that the command `less /etc/passwd` is used to access `/etc/passwd`, and that `grep` is used to find/search for a certain string pattern, but that's about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `grep`:

```
$ grep -F "ubu" /etc/passwd
```

This uses `grep -F` to search for the literal string `ubu` in the file `/etc/passwd`.  Without the `-F`, `grep` would treat `ubu` as a regular expression.  In this case it wouldn't make a difference, but if the string contained characters, like `*`, which is "special" in regular expressions, then this is how you could make them "less special".

`grep` will return all lines that contains the match.

If `ubu` is a username (a *complete* username, not just a part of one), then the following will additionally do a lookup in any directory service (like LDAP or NIS/YP) that the system may be using:

```
$ getent passwd ubu
```

Comment: Also if I want to search for a string in the `/home` directory,can I do it the same way? or is there anything else to it?

Comment: @AhmadKhateeb In all files under `/home`?  Try `find /home -type f -exec grep -HF "ubu" {} +` (see the manual for `grep` for the `-H` flag).

Comment: @AhmadKahateeb You have to use find here because you are searching in a directory and not in a single file or in a small set of files that you can list on the command line.

Comment: Or see if your `grep` supports the `-r` option for recursive search (FreeBSD and GNU `grep` do)

Comment: @Philippos Yes, I don't know why I didn't think about that...

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start with a tutorial to learn the basics.

If you simply looked for [`grep`'s man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/grep1.html), you would have been able to figure it out quite easily.

You can basically do `grep "ubu" /etc/passwd`.